# How to create a menu with this effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, effects

Trying to create a menu with - [this effect](https://www.artlebedev.ru/) .

**My code**

```
var lastScroll = 0;

    window.onscroll = function() {
      var navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');
      var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      var body = document.querySelector('body');

      if (lastScroll - scrollTop > 0) {
        body.classList.add('body-fixed');
        navbar.classList.add('fixed');
      } else {
        body.classList.remove('body-fixed');
        navbar.classList.remove('fixed');
      }

      lastScroll = scrollTop;

    }
```

```js
var lastScroll = 0;

window.onscroll = function() {
  var navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');
  var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var body = document.querySelector('body');

  if (lastScroll - scrollTop > 0) {
    body.classList.add('body-fixed');
    navbar.classList.add('fixed');
  } else {
    body.classList.remove('body-fixed');
    navbar.classList.remove('fixed');
  }

  lastScroll = scrollTop;

}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 2000px;
}
body.body-fixed{
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.navbar {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background: #00f;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  transition: padding 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar"></nav>
```

I can't create an effect so that the menu disappears smoothly when I scroll the page to down. I can not understand how this is implemented on the website example.

Tell me how to properly implement this effect for the menu.

Thank you in advance. I will be glad to any help.

Answer (score 0):

The smooth translation is done using css property `transform: translate(0px, 0px)` modified with proper values on scroll.

Instead of appending a class, you can directly change element's style using js.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate

You might also want look into CSS transitions.